# ASP.NET GridView Sort?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview, linqdatasource

I'm performing a query with a sort in the Selecting event of the LinqDataSource. I'm then casting my query to a list and assigning it to the result. I'm using this data source in an ASP.NET gridview.

I can see the list is sorted but when the ASP.NET gridview does not seem to be respecting the sort order. How can I get the gridview to respect my default sort order?

Answer (score 1):

See, this is why I post here. I spent 30 minutes trying to figure this out. Post here. And 20 seconds later I figure out my own answer.

I had a SortOrder defined in the declarative syntax for the Linqdatasource.